# Parse.com Push notification fails to be received

Tags: android, eclipse, push-notification, parse-platform

Parse sends the push notifications but the android devices fails to receive. 
I have Followed the Parse tutorial very carefully I don't know what else I can do to get it working. 
Please Help. Thank You.

My manifest.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="org.marsfirst.mars_app"
    android:versionCode="12"
    android:versionName="1.8.4" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="org.marsfirst.mars_app.pushnotifications.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />


    <permission
        android:name="org.marsfirst.mars_app"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="org.marsfirst.mars_app.pushnotifications.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="org.marsfirst.mars_app.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="org.marsfirst.mars_app.Signup"
            android:label="@string/signup"
            android:parentActivityName="org.marsfirst.mars_app.MainActivity" >
            <intent-filter />

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="org.marsfirst.mars_app.MainActivity" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="org.marsfirst.mars_app.MainPage"
            android:label="Main Page" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="org.marsfirst.mars_app.Webpage"
            android:label="Website"
            android:parentActivityName="org.marsfirst.mars_app.MainPage" >
            <intent-filter />

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="org.marsfirst.mars_app.MainPage" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="org.marsfirst.mars_app.TeamNews"
            android:label="Team News"
            android:parentActivityName="org.marsfirst.mars_app.MainPage" >
            <intent-filter />

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="org.marsfirst.mars_app.MainPage" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="org.marsfirst.mars_app.OprPage"
            android:label="OPR Page"
            android:parentActivityName="org.marsfirst.mars_app.MainPage" >
            <intent-filter />

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="org.marsfirst.mars_app.MainPage" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="org.marsfirst.mars_app.MechPage"
            android:label="Mechanical Page"
            android:parentActivityName="org.marsfirst.mars_app.MainPage" >
            <intent-filter />

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="org.marsfirst.mars_app.MainPage" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="org.marsfirst.mars_app.DriveNews"
            android:label="Drive News"
            android:parentActivityName="org.marsfirst.mars_app.MainPage" >
            <intent-filter />

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="org.marsfirst.mars_app.MainPage" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="org.marsfirst.mars_app.ProgramingPage"
            android:label="Programming Page"
            android:parentActivityName="org.marsfirst.mars_app.MainPage" >
            <intent-filter />

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="org.marsfirst.mars_app.MainPage" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="org.marsfirst.mars_app.Application"
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        </activity>

        <service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />

        <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver
            android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
                <category android:name="org.marsfirst.mars_app" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Then my Application.class

```
import com.parse.Parse;
import com.parse.ParseAnalytics;
import com.parse.ParseInstallation;
import com.parse.PushService;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Application extends android.app.Application {

    public Application() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        {
            Parse.initialize(this, "key","key");

            PushService.setDefaultPushCallback(Application.this, MainActivity.class);
            ParseAnalytics.trackAppOpened(getIntent());
            ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();
        }
    }

    private Intent getIntent() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }}
```

Answer (score 0):

The entries in your AndroidManifest.xml are wrong,

```
<permission
        android:name="org.marsfirst.mars_app"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
```

Change this to

```
 <permission
        android:name="org.marsfirst.mars_app.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
```

This entry occurs twice remove the duplicate and replace it with

```
<uses-permission android:name="org.marsfirst.mars_app.pushnotifications.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

Change to ,

<uses-permission android:name="org.marsfirst.mars_app.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
```

Answer (score 0):

i have successfully implementing the parse push with this manifest
    file ...

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="your package name"
        android:versionCode="1"
        android:versionName="1.0" >

        <uses-sdk
            android:minSdkVersion="15"
            android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

        <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
            <activity
                android:name="your package name.YourActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>

            <service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />

            <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
                </intent-filter>
            </receiver>
            <receiver android:name="your package name.YourCustomReceiver" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
                    <action android:name="your package name.UPDATE_STATUS" />
                </intent-filter>
            </receiver>
        </application>

    </manifest>
```

for any further query please let me know..